# Best practice for REST API tasks (not CRUD)

Tags: api, rest, crud

I'm implementing a REST API and am hoping for input on methods which don't strictly fit the CRUD model. Here is a generic example:

I POST a "dog" object to my "dogs" collection.
I PATCH a collar on the new dog (dogs/1).
I now want the dog to roll over.

Assuming "roll over" is a one-time task which doesn't change the state of the dog, how would you implement this? I have the following ideas:

Option 1:

```
POST dogs/1
{
  task: "roll over" 
}
```

Option 2:

```
POST tasks/
{
  task: "roll over"
  id: 1
}
```

Option 3:

```
GET dogs/1/rollOver
```

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming "roll over" is a one-time task which doesn't change the state of the dog, how would you implement this?

Short answer:

```
POST /tasks

{
    "task": "roll over",
    "id": "/dogs/1"
}
```

Longer answer: one of the important constraints of REST is the uniform interface - which includes the fact that the semantics of the self descriptive messages are the same for all resources everywhere.

`GET` is a lousy way to "start a task" because the semantics of GET are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), which is to say effectively read only, meaning that anybody anywhere can request a representation of that resource at any time.  Think about browsers pre-fetching the task link to save time, or a web crawler coming along to add your task resource for indexing.

That leaves a choice between

```
POST /dogs/1
POST /tasks
```

Now, because POST is an unsafe method, there is an interesting caching wrinkle to consider.  A non-error response to an unsafe request will [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) a cached representation of the target resource.

Normally, if you are making a change to a resource (ex: PUT /foo), that's *exactly* what you want.

But here, it sounds like the "roll over" tasks is not supposed to change the representation of `/dogs/1`.  If the representation of that resource isn't going to change, then I *don't* want to invalidate it, and I will instead target some other resource with the request.

There is, of course, nothing particularly magic about the spelling `/tasks`.  It could just as easily be `/dogs/1/tasks`, or `/tasks/dogs/1` or `/dogs/1/rollOver` or `/b79d1e50-44eb-4c51-bfc6-ef0d94c15fdc`.